# Nonblocking io_service::run

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, blocking, nonblocking

I'm trying to implement a single C++ application, that holds two processing loops. Currently the first processing loop (boost's io_service::run) blocks the execution of the second one.

Approaches utilizing threads or std::async approaches failed. (I don't have experience/background on multi-threading).

Is there an elegant way to run the io_service::run in an other thread, while still executing the callbacks upon incoming UDP datagrams?

Main-File:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

    void callback(const int&);
private:
    // ... (hopefully) non-relevant stuff...
};

int main()
{

  Foo foo_obj;

  // I need to run this function (blocking) but the constructor is blocking (io_server::run())
  run();

  return 0;
}


Foo::Foo(){
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    UDP_Server UDP_Server(io);

    // Set function to be called on received message
    UDP_Server.add_handler(std::bind(&Foo::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    // This function should be non-blocking
    // -> tried several things, like threads, async, ... (unfortunately not successful)
    io.run();
}

// realization of callback function here (see class definition)
```

Included custom "library":

```
class UDP_Server
{
public:
    UDP_Server(boost::asio::io_service&);

    void add_handler(std::function<void(int)>);

private:
    // Function handle
    std::function<void(int)> callbackFunctionHandle;

    // Functions
    void start_receive();
    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t);

    // ... (hopefully) non-relevant stuff...
};

// Constructor
UDP_Server::UDP_Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), UDP_PORT)){

}

// Store a callback function (class foo) to be called whenever a message is received
void UDP_Server::add_handler(std::function<void(int)>  callbackFunction){
    try
    {
        callbackFunctionHandle = callbackFunction;
        start_receive();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

// Async receive
UDP_Server::start_receive()
{
  socket_.async_receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
      boost::bind(&UDP_Server::handle_receive, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

// When message is received
void UDP_Server::handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
  {

    // ... do smth. with the received data ...

    // Call specified function in Foo class
    callbackFunctionHandle(some_integer);

    start_receive();
}
else{
  // ... handle errors
}

}
```

Comment: What stops you from using a single `io_service`?

Comment: I'm using a single `io_service` the other blocking function (represented by the single `run()`) is a ROS related `ros::spin()`

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I also had a look at `run_one()`. The thing is that I constantly receive messages via UDP, which should be processed as soon as possible. Therefore, I should stick to `run()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at what they did in [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/jackal_base/html/jackal__base_8cpp_source.html):

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
/** your code here **/
boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
ros::spin();
```

So you basically start the blocking call to io_service::run() in a separate thread from the ros::spin().

If you start that bound to a single cpu-node (in order to not waste 2 cpu-nodes with waiting commands) your scheduler might handle stuff.

Comment: I'm getting ```Bus error: 10``` error with this code and I have no idea why.